# Connection to socket.IO from angularJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

This question describes the same problem than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768831/cannot-connect-to-socket-io-from-angular-app).

However the provided solution doesn't work for me.

The log of my angular app looks like  (the last digit increments every second or so):

```
GET https://54.86.104.202/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1421524885321-3 404 (Not Found)
XHR finished loading: GET "https://54.86.104.202/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1421524885321-3".
```

I've set the server as follows :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var sslOptions = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('/var/ssl/server.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/ssl/server.crt'),
      ca: fs.readFileSync('/var/ssl/ca.crt'),
      agent: false,
      requestCert: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    };
var server = https.createServer(sslOptions);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(9876);
```

So to me it appears that everything should be working fine, but it seems that the socket server isn't started. Any idea why?

The same result happens when I use a snippet from one of my old apps :

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(https.createServer(sslOptions).listen(9876));
```

Could it have something to do with the fact that I'm using socket.IO 1.x ?

Comment: Your server is listening on port 9876 and you're requesting without any (i.e. port 80)

Comment: Mmm. I guess I've passed the ballmer peak. Thanks mate!